# Digg-style pagination customize in template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-endless-pagination

I am using django-el-pagination package and trying to implement digg-style pagination on my home template. I am displaying it with..

```
{% get_pages %}
{{ pages.get_rendered }}
```

and it is showing like this <1234567> which is fine but

1. I want to add some css or class to change the way it look.

If you have any other way to achieve this. Please suggest..

please tell how can I customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to make it looks something like this or like whatever you want:

[image]

Here is an example:

```
{% get_pages %}
<div class="pagination">
    {% for page in pages %}
        <li class="page-item"><a href="{{ page.url }}" class="page-link">{{ page.number }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can check the documentation here: https://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#get-pages to check all the available options for *get_pages*